# Type hinting in interface

Tags: php, oop, interface

Why should the class type-hint be 100% same with the interface?
I mean, why can't it accept implementing class as type hint?

To make it clear,

```
<?php
interface MyInterface
{
    public function doMethod(SomeInterface $a)
    {
    }
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
    public function doMethod(ClassThatImplementsSomeInterface $a)
     {
     }
}
```

Error: `Fatal error: Declaration of MyClass::doMethod() must be compatible with that of MyInterface::doMethod()`

Since the class type hinting implements `SomeInterface`, I expect it doesn't break the contract.
Why do I want it? Because of the advantages of interface flexibility.
The same goes for abstract class.
If I rewrite the code so that method 'do' has no type-hint, I know that it will 'fix' it.
But, somehow I think I should define the contract that type-hinting of `$a` must implement `SomeInterface`.
And, Why don't I just use the same type-hint which is `SomeInterface` ?
That's because there are methods that don't exist in `SomeInterface` that I need.
So, what's the point of this limitation?

Reproducable codepad: http://codepad.org/2PLd8AmV

Comment: I added some information, good question!

Comment: Your interface is saying "I'll use one of these thanks" and you implementation says "Yea well I'm using one of these instead"... I don't see where the question is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is simply, that you **need** to be able to rely on the object that the interface requires.

**Real world example:**

Interface requires `APPLE`.

You now try to implement a class that says `I require a GREEN APPLE` (it's still an apple!).

Someone now tries to implement your INTERFACE and put it into the class for the green apple. He tries to put in a `RED APPLE` which is compatible with `APPLE` but not with `GREEN APPLE`.

=> bang, contract broken!

**Coding example:**

```
interface MyInterface
{
    public function doMethod(SomeInterface $a);
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface
{
    public function doMethod(ClassThatImplementsSomeInterface $a) { }
}

class DifferentClass implements SomeInterface { }

$ding = new MyClass();
$ding->doMethod(new DifferentClass);
```

This wouldn't work because `DifferentClass` is not `ClassThatImplementsSomeInterface`!

Comment: Actually, in my case, it's about event listener. This is the problem : [http://codepad.org/ZKYUYcid](http://codepad.org/ZKYUYcid) ... Please take a look..  
I'm confused whether I should remove the type-hinting in the `handle` method in Listener class or whether I should rewrite the type-hint in the `ChangeUserName` class from `UserHasLoggedIn` into `Event`.

Comment: Or, should I code a new interface called `ChangeUserNameInterface` that extends `Listener` interface  and let my `ChangeUserName` class implement it? But, I think it's too expensive since there are so many event listeners which means that there'll be so many event listener interface.. I get confused now ._.

Comment: You could combine interfaces and other classes using abstract classes but I think interfaces are best (search for "loose couling php" to see explanation!).

Answer (score 1):

Type hinting a different class changes the contract.  Your interface says "anything that implements me must use a certain type in this method".  Your actual implementation says that the method actually needs to use a different type.

As long as I have an object that implements "MyInterface", I know that there exists a `do` method.  I also know that this method takes one argument that has to be `SomeInterface`.  Because of the interface, I don't actually need to know or care about any specifics of the object (which specific implementation of the interface that it is).

However, if the object that I have is of type `MyObject` that isn't the case!  I actually need to have a `ClassThatImplementsSomeInterface` object!  If my object isn't this type, then my program crashes.  Possibly randomly if I have factory methods creating objects.  I can no longer trust that `MyInterface` objects have a consistent implementation and have to check to make sure that the argument that I want to pass it is the correct one.

The problem that you are having is a good smell that your classes and interfaces aren't properly defined.  `MyObject` may not actually be an instance of `SomeInterface`.  Or `SomeInterface` needs to actually take a `ClassThatImplementsSomeInterface` instead.

***Addendum***

Based on your code example, remove the argument from the handle function.  Have the `__construct` arguments for the specific types of `Listener` objects take a particular implementation of `Event`.

```
interface Event
{
    public function getName();
}

interface Listener
{
    public function handle();
}

class UserHasLoggedIn implements Event
{
    public function __construct($name, $id)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'UserHasLoggedIn';
    }
}


class ChangeUserName implements Listener
{
    private $event;

    public function __construct(UserHasLoggedIn $event)
    {
        $this->event = $event;
    }

    public function handle()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: This is the specific implementation of it : [http://codepad.org/ZKYUYcid](http://codepad.org/ZKYUYcid) .. Please take a look at it.. What's your suggestion to solve my problem?

Comment: I have added to my answer with a suggestion.  Though without knowing more about what you are trying to do, there is limited advice that I can provide.

Comment: Still, the interface doesn't define any contracts for the event. What if the __construct parameter is not an Event or Event-derived object ? I'd like to set the contract

Comment: You use a Factory class that takes an `Event` object and returns the correct Listener based on its type.  You can't enforce via an interface that the __construct parameters be Event or Event derived because you want to be specific about which particular object each individual listener will get.

Comment: Your problem in general can be solved using the Observer pattern as described here: http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html